# Can't connect to Sybase server

Tags: linux, sybase, sap-ase, gentoo

I just successfully installed Sybase ASE 16.02 Dev Edition on my Gentoo box. According to this command, the server is running:

```
igor@IgorReinCloud /opt $ /opt/sap/ASE-16_0/install/showserver 
F S UID        PID  PPID  C PRI  NI ADDR SZ WCHAN  STIME TTY          TIME CMD
0 S igor     20774 20773  0  80   0 -  9270 poll_s Dec14 ?        00:00:00 /opt/sap/ASE-16_0/bin/backupserver -e/opt/sap/data/ASE-16_0/install/IGORREINCLOUD_BS.log -N25 -C20 -I/opt/sap/data/interfaces -M/opt/sap/ASE-16_0/bin/sybmultbuf -SIGORREINCLOUD_BS
0 S igor     20655 20654  1  80   0 - 694197 futex_ Dec14 ?       00:47:25 /opt/sap/ASE-16_0/bin/dataserver -sIGORREINCLOUD -d/opt/sap/data/data/master.dat -e/opt/sap/data/ASE-16_0/install/IGORREINCLOUD.log -c/opt/sap/data/ASE-16_0/IGORREINCLOUD.cfg -M/opt/sap/data/ASE-16_0 -N/opt/sap/data/ASE-16_0/sysam/IGORREINCLOUD.properties -i/opt/sap/data
```

However, when I try to connect, I get this error:

```
igor@IgorReinCloud /opt $ /opt/sap/OCS-16_0/bin/isql64 -Usa -SIGORREINCLOUD
Password: 
CT-LIBRARY error:
    ct_connect(): directory service layer: internal directory control layer error: Requested server name not found.
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: @jww, Perhaps it is better to ask this in "Database Administrator". But since I was installing Development Edition of the server I thought that it is better fit here with developers. Close it if you think it does not belong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify that your ASE server "IGORREINCLOUD" is defined in the file $SYBASE/interfaces (with $SYBASE your SYBASE home folder defined in your Linux user)

Vince

Comment: how do I do that? Sorry I completely new to the big Sybase (I was working with Sybase SQL Anywhere in the past). Also if its not - how to add it?

Comment: Nevermind that. Looks like its just a text file. After adding the required info, everything works. Thank you.